# python error: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a function with an interactive input to tell you what the 'SMILES' formula is for a fatty acid (chemical compound) but I keep getting this error:

```
def fatty_gen(chain_length, db_position, db_orientation):
    "Returns the SMILES code of the fatty acid, given its chain length, db position, db orientation"
    chain_length=input("What is the chain length/number of C?")
    chain_length2=int(chain_length)
    db_position = input("On which carbon does the double bond first appear")
    db_position2=int(db_position)
    db_orientation= input("What is the orientation of the double bond")
    db_orientation2=str(db_orientation)

    if db_orientation2 =="Z":
        a="/C=C\\"
    elif db_orientation2=="E":
        a="\C=C\\"
    else: a =""

    return "C"*((db_position2)-1) + a + "C"*(chain_length2-db_position2-1)


<ipython-input-2-20b88ae22368> in fatty_gen(chain_length, db_position, db_orientation)
     13         a="\C=C\\"
     14 
---> 15     return "C"*((db_position2)-1) + a + "C"*(chain_length2-db_position2-1)
     16 fatty_gen(1,1,1)

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment
```

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment

Comment: `a` will be undefined if non of the `if` blocks is executed

Comment: @MosesKoledoye In this case, why is the 'if/elif' not being executed despite it being under my function?

Comment: Presumably the value is neither Z nor E.

Answer (score 1):

If `db_orientation2` is neither `"Z"` nor `"E"` `a` variable is not defined.

You need to add `else` clause like this:

```
if db_orientation2 == "Z":
    a = "/C=C\\"
elif db_orientation2 == "E":
    a = "\C=C\\"
else:
    a = "something else"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion, that did indeed work. However, now, my output is showing two backslash \\ within the string instead of just one

Comment: Read about escaping in python strings. Or use raw strings like `r'\/\/\'`

Answer (score 0):

```
if db_orientation2 =="Z":
    a="/C=C\\"
elif db_orientation2=="E":
    a="\C=C\\"
elif db_orientation2=="":
    a="/C=C\\"
else: a=""
```

Anyone know why the backslashes are appearing twice, despite it supposed to be understood as just one backslash?